# Changed address of value on second import

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, memory-address, python-module

I'm struggling with understanding why in case, when I import one module that defines variable and access it from one module, it has one address and, when later import defining module in another module, it has yet another address.

**Test case:**

```
#definer.py
value = 0

#firstModule.py
import definer
print(id(definer.value))  # outputs i.e. 1453872004

#otherModule.py
import definer
print(id(definer.value))  # outputs 1453872212
```

Shouldn't it be the same because in `otherModule.py` it is importing cached `definer.py` and thus it should access already created object or did I miss point of imports? Does otherModule create local copy or it's indeed creating new value?

Comment: are you calling these methods from the same process?

Comment: I can't reproduce; as long as you import both `firstModule` and `otherModule` into the same Python process, the `definer.value` matches. Your example code doesn't seem to be a [MCVE], as you fail to show how you import `firstModule`/`otherModule`; if you are doing this in separate processes, a mismatch is expected.

Comment: @ShadowRanger both imports were made in the main process. Unfortunately, yes, I did not specify that some work with is done in another processes, but as far as I know in Threading threads have shared memory.

Comment: @ntrme: Are these `id`s being `print`ed in the same process? In the CPython reference interpreter, `0` is a singleton (implementation detail), so even if you did something weird that causes `value` to be redefined in two places, the `id` would match *unless* you had separate processes involved (and even then, I think it would only occur if you were using `subprocess` or `multiprocessing` on Windows, where the workers are made via spawn, not fork). Alternatively, is any of your code assigning to `definer.value`? If so, the `id` would change after the assignment.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, there was assigning but later in the code, after the print statements.Print statements were made from one thread (main), did double check on that. So I've rearranged code that from now on I don't access just value and work with it, but create an object, where I set and get that value. Now it's working as intended, that means I work with one object (at certain address) and later on all threads are using this object as well. I'll try to replicate initial problem in simple setting and update question ASAP. Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 enable_generated_tests_p  cat firstModule.py
import definer
import os

print('pid:',os.getpid(), 'definer.value:',id(definer.value))

 enable_generated_tests_p  cat secondModule.py
import definer
import os

print('pid:',os.getpid(), 'definer.value:',id(definer.value))

 enable_generated_tests_p  cat ThirdModule.py
import firstModule
import secondModule

 enable_generated_tests_p  python firstModule.py
pid: 73848 definer.value: 4565266656

 enable_generated_tests_p  python secondModule.py
pid: 73906 definer.value: 4428878048

 enable_generated_tests_p  python ThirdModule.py
pid: 73964 definer.value: 4442521824
pid: 73964 definer.value: 4442521824
```

id() - Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

In your case, you have been running your firstModule and secondModule using different processes/subprocesses so you get different IDs as seen above.